# word-spacing property is not working in opera mini

Tags: css, forms, opera-mini

css word-spacing property for paragraph not working in opera mini (for mobile). I have tried like this-

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 try-test">
    <?php 
        foreach ($newsArr as $item){
          echo $item['News']['title'];  
        }
    ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

css :-

```
.try-test{
    font-family: SolimanLipi !important;
    word-spacing: 2px;
 }
```

Comment: It's most likely isn't supported by opera mini.

Comment: Letter/Word-Spacing is not supported by Opera Mini it would seem - http://caniuse.com/#search=letter-spacing

Comment: my paragraph make big space in word have it  another way for less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug of Opera which is our bug reporting system with the id DSK-357174.

Comment: how can i solve word spacing i saw some website doing well. can you suggest me ?

Comment: well unfortunately there is no way to do it with css but yes there is always a way this must be possible with some js...could you please share the link of that website

Comment: can you give me any hints for js

Comment: `$('.try-test').text().replace(/ /g, '\     ');` with this jquery you can replace single space with multiple spaces